# How should I append an element to each sequence data by tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to get sequence data with char2int['EOS'] added behind by tf.data.Dataset.
The codes I wrote are as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

def _get_generator(list_of_text, char2int):
    def gen():
        for text in list_of_text:
            yield [char2int[x] for x in text] # transform char to int
    return gen

def get_dataset(list_of_text, char2int):
    gen = _get_generator(list_of_text, char2int)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (tf.int32), tf.TensorShape([None]))

    dataset = dataset.map(lambda seq: seq+[char2int['EOS']])  # append EOS to the end of line

    data_iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

    return dataset, data_iter

char2int = {'EOS':1, 'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4}
list_of_text = ['aaa', 'abc'] # the sequence data

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    dataset, data_iter = get_dataset(list_of_text, char2int)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(data_iter.initializer)
        tt1 = sess.run(data_iter.get_next())
        tt2 = sess.run(data_iter.get_next())
        print(tt1)  # got [3 3 3] but I want [2 2 2 1]
        print(tt2)  # god [3 4 5] but I want [2 3 4 1]
```

But I can't get what I want. It performs element-wise addition to each data. How should I fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your map function you are adding each value by 1 instead of concatenating the value. You can change your `_get_generator` to :

```
def _get_generator(list_of_text, char2int):
   def gen():
     for text in list_of_text:
        yield [char2int[x] for x in text] + [char2int['EOS']]# transform char to int
   return gen
```

and remove `dataset.map` call.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just wonder why the codes in dataset.map doesn't work. Because  lambda seq: seq+[char2int['EOS']]  should be a small function that perform appending char2int['EOS'] behind seq. At least it works when I input a string for it but why it's just perform element-wise addition in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

As Vijay points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50466385/3574081), the `+` operator on a `tf.Tensor` of type `tf.int32` performs *addition* rather than *concatenation*. To concatenate an additional symbol onto the end of the sequence, instead use [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) in the `Dataset.map()`:

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda seq: tf.concat([seq, [char2int['EOS']]], axis=0)
```